# Examples of locally connected sets

Tags: general-topology

What are some examples of locally connected sets? I am trying to understand what it means for the Mandelbrot set to be locally connected.

Comment: ZxR , ZxZ, RxR.

Comment: $\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : (x-2)^2 + y^2 < 1 \vee (x+2)^2 + y^2 < 1 \}$

Answer (score 2):

Take for instance:

$\bullet$$\mathbb{R}^n$ is a locally connected space.

$\bullet$ An interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is a locally connected set with respect to the standard topology.

$\bullet$ Or a union of intervals,for example $[0,1] \cup[3,4]$ with respect to the standardo topology.

We know that a path connected set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected,thus a locally path connected in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally connected.

Thus $[0,1] \cup [3,4]$ is locally path connected thus locally connected.

$\bullet$ Take the open unit disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$  namely $B(0,1)=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2<1\}$ or an open rectangle.

$\bullet$ Take a discrete topological space.

A discrete space $X$ is totally disconnected but it is locally connected because for every $x \in X$ the noeighborhood $\{x\}$ is connected.

$\bullet$ Take the set $X=\{x\}$ with the topology $T=\{\{x\},\emptyset\}$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, the concept is getting clearer now. Can an infinite union of disjoint set still be locally connected, say, the union of all open unit intervals (n,n+1) with $n \in Z$?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would also be useful to see an example of a connected set that is not locally connected: the topologist's sine curve $(\{0\} × [-1, 1]) ∪ \{(x, \sin\frac{1}{x}): x ∈ (0, 1]\}$ is such a space. It is connected, but not locally connected at the points $\{0\} × [-1, 1]$. For example the point $(0, 0)$ cannot be separated by clopen sets from points $(\frac{1}{kπ}, 0)$, but this cannot be witnessed locally.